# F6 Navbar not responsive, showing all content together

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-NqI559iHqiWe5VxDi9mXE8i83ghn8Ru8BINyiPN7lDg=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
      <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
      <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="#0">One</a>
            <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
              <li><a href="#0">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#0">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4/foundation.min.js" integrity="sha256-6Po73qUOfEfrvKtDy88HN0Xx6wjx3ZlngccJjsIVpIg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my all of my code. I've added Foundation's CSS and JS plugins, and the code for the F6 Responsive Navbar. But the navbar doesn't work like it should, even in the snippet. It should be just the `ul`s on large screens, but on large screens and small screens, I'm getting everything together. Why does this happen? I've tested cross-browser and cross-CDN, but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `js` and `cdn` script in `body` tags. Put your last `js` and `cdn` script section between `head` tags and write a script for `$(document).foundation();` in body tags.

Then try it, I hope it will work for you, because it works for me.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxLBBE

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my end after upgrading from F6.2 to F6.3. The solution that worked for me was adding the following block to my `foundation_and_overrides.scss` file:

```
.is-drilldown li, .is-drilldown .menu > li {
  display: block;
}
```

For context, I dug into the Foundation stylesheets and found something interesting. Previously, Foundation's `drilldown` component had this styling:

```
~/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/foundation-rails-6.2.3.0/vendor/assets/scss/components/_drilldown.scss
.is-drilldown li {
  display: block !important;
}
```

This styling changed in the update to F6.3:

```
~/gems/foundation-rails-6.3.0.0/vendor/assets/scss/components/_drilldown.scss

.is-drilldown li {
  display: block;
}
```

While it's a best practice to avoid using `!important`, in this case removing `!important` seems to have caused the issue you described because the F6.3 styling for the `drilldown` component is getting overridden by the following styling in the F6.3 `menu` component:

```
~/gems/foundation-rails-6.3.0.0/vendor/assets/scss/components/_menu.scss
.menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope that helps!